# Integral inequality: mean of function versus mean of function squared

Tags: integration

I am studying the behavior of the following quantity

$$\frac{\int x f(x)^2 \ dx}{\int f(x)^2 \ dx}-2\frac{\int x f(x) \ dx}{\int f(x) \ dx}$$
where $f(x)\ge 0$ is a compact integrable function and we are integrating over all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Is there any way to bound the behavior of this quantity?

Comment: My first two thoughts are integration by parts and Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Does $f$ have compact support?

Comment: @mrprottolo yes

Comment: Use Karamata's inequality